# Automate GUI usage on windows for an ERP program

Tags: windows, automation, interop, autohotkey, autoit

I'm trying to automate a task: I want to regularly open our ERP system and export some data. (The ERP system does not have an API)

I'm quite alright with coding (R, python, scripting) and I think I might be able to string something together to automate this.

The flow would be something like this:

- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Open the program
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Wait 2 seconds roughly click enter once to enter program
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Close all remaining open windows
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Open a certain window to show a summary of certain data
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Change tab
- **[By using the mouse!]** Click a specific area on the open window; find menu that opens (often a bit away), click certain option
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Enter to save dataset
- *[Keyboard shortcut available]* Close windows, close program

I see three options:

1. Trying to automate this task in Python or some operating system specific scripting package (autohotkey, autoit): upside should be no costs, downside might be frailty of solution and time investment
2. Query the underlying SQL tables which the ERP uses to store our data. However this option is not supported by the software vendor and the tables might be hard to read and interpret (e.g. data columns not named in an obvious way).
3. Use an existing RPA software such as uiPath: Could be costly and not clear if it works
4. Work with the provider of the ERP system to implement an option: This would be quite reliable, but costly for our company

I would like to start with option #1: I would be grateful for some pointers how I might start implementing this.

Comment: Give Autoit a try. You can find the relevant parameters for the window handles and so on wirh AutoitWindowInfo.exe

Answer (score 0):

From most robust to least robust:

- Query the underlying SQL tables
- Write a UiPath Studio workflow
- Write a Python / AutoIt / AutoHotkey script

From least expensive to most expensive:

- Query the underlying SQL tables (probably free)
- Write a Python / AutoIt / AutoHotkey script (free)
- Write a UiPath Studio workflow (non-free license)

Beware that  Python, AutoHotkey, and AutoIt have lower quality selectors (similar to CSS / Xpath selectors) than UiPath. So if the application changes or you run it on a different computer, the non-UiPath options are more likely to break.